# Automatically delete stale environments in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am looking for ways to delete stale environments from GitLab.

Is there any automated approach to clean up stale environments on a schedule without manually deleting each environment? I am hoping to run the "stop environment" option, which is wired to perform a deletion of resources used in the environment as part of this clean-up process.

Comment: you mean like a gitlab api?
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#stop-an-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you define a stale environment, a neat way to automatically clean up environments used for feature deployments is to use the `auto_stop_in` [key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#stop-an-environment-after-a-certain-time-period).

With this setting the environment will be automatically stopped after the defined timespan which is newly set after each deployment.

```
review_app:
  script: deploy-review-app
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    on_stop: stop_review_app
    auto_stop_in: 1 week
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```

Comment: that was perfectly what I needed . Thanks

Comment: that's nice, but it only stops and doesn't delete the environments.  you end up with hundreds of stopped environments.

Answer (score 1):

> that's nice, but it only stops and doesn't delete the environments

[GitLab 16.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/02/15/gitlab-16-9-released/#allow-users-to-cleanup-partial-resources-from-failed-deployments) (February 2024) addresses that:

> ### Allow users to cleanup partial resources from failed deployments
>
> The Environment [`auto_stop_in`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environmentauto_stop_in) functionality was updated to run the job from the last finished pipeline, instead of the last successful pipeline. This avoids edge cases where the auto stop job can not run because of not having any successful pipelines.
>
> This behaviour might be considered a breaking change in some situations. The new behaviour is currently behind a feature flag, and will become the default in 17.0, and at the same time, we are going to deprecate the old behaviour to be removed from GitLab in 18.0. We recommend everyone to start transitioning or to configure the feature flag immediately to minimize the risks of the breaking change at the first 17.x upgrade.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#run-a-pipeline-job-when-environment-is-stopped) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/435128).